# Type "prototype" cannot be used to index class type

Tags: typescript, class, prototype

According to Typescript documentation, the correct type for specifying a class constructor is the following:

```js
type Class = { new (...args: any[]): {} }
```

And if you try to index this type like this:

```js
type ClassPrototype = { new (...args: any[]): {} }["prototype"]
// OR EVEN
type ClassPrototype = Class["prototype"]
```

Everything is fine with the compiler while if you try something like the following, an error occurs:

```js
type PrototypeOf<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }> = T["prototype"] // <-- Type '"prototype"' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
```

And I am not sure why this happens. If I am able to index `Class` with `Class["prototype"]` why am I not when it is a generic `<T extends Class>` with `T["prototype"]`? The solution i have found temporarily is changing `<T extends Class>` with `<T extends { prototype }>` but it doesn't look clean.

I have included the context I want to use this in here: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5KgXigbygOwgdygAoA6MhAJwHMkAuKBHEAbQF0BKezAXyl4FgAUKEixEKAAoUA9sFnhoGeMiTMARGBlyRENayFCdUKbPmQA8gDMAPABUoEAB7AIOACaplKAHzoot9U1THT0oAHowqGsAWmioAHUACxAoYESAS1QgtwBXAGMIVEYHChkKAH4DQQioAFUAZQBRWABBJqgAOUbGgBFe2iE88VQWuwdnVw8sXAJiMhJKGnpGFg4uXm5fTCEoXYYiRfpbTn9ArTNdViwdvduKCGAcihwoIZVrwVvbm6++H7-BNwqjUALIpBB5R4IOBQfDSCgAa0o0hy7gGwgUxnOOisAH0xk4XO5UJggtoFMsmJs-AENNiFKEqm8UFAWvj7ITJiSoGSLpSUtTtp89ggDtQjidabyQlchb9dvdHs9XsMPvKvv9bkDhbttdwgA)

Comment: I've provided an answer, but I want to add that this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Whatever you are trying to do, I think there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class constructor's `prototype` property has a type that is just that class as a type.

An example to help with that word salad:

```
class Class {
  methodA(): void {}
}
const a: Class = Class.prototype // fine
type Test = Class['prototype'] // error
```

Here the value `Class` (the constructor) when called with `new` produces a value of type `Class` (an instance).

To be honest, I've no idea what typescript allows the runtime access of `Class.prototype` and not the type of `Class['prototype']`. (But it's probably a deliberate trade off between making dealing with classes nice, at the cost of of making prototypical patterns harder, since classes are more common in modern codebases than manually building up prototypes)

But given that the type `Class['prototype']` doesn't work on a *real class*, then you probably shouldn't expect that exist on an abstract class constructor type either.

---

I'm guessing you probably want [`InstanceType<T>` here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) instead.

```
type ClassConstructor = { new (...args: any[]): ClassInstance }
type ClassInstance = { methodA(): void }

type A = ClassConstructor['prototype'] // type is any, so this is not useful anyway
type B = InstanceType<ClassConstructor> // type is ClassInstance
type C = InstanceType<ClassConstructor>['methodA'] // type is void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5JgewHZOAJwK4DGwaOUAvFAN5QYQDuUAFAHSsI4DmSAXFAhiADaAXQCUveMiQBJLMH4FoAXwBQoSLEQpZ2BdArUAthGAALNABMAgo3FQAbmgCWFqKrXhoV8pqno5+EQkggDkYDhoxOoQIcJQAPTxUNFQTkh8AgA0UEhoyaZpqekYkVB4SBAAZnhwGSB0CCAeGgBCPjryGIoAKp4APJIo-tiBxDgAfAlJKYWDMnJ6zdAw7QtdEL2QA1qomCOEY+OhxmaWVrFTyZ5FDs4WQA)

Comment: My bad. For some reason, I have never been aware of `InstanceType` existence. Looks like I just missed it and It is just what I was looking for now. Thank you! :)